# Retrieve type of error

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a handler for my client-side errors using the `onerror` event. What I'm really interested in is the *type* of [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) thrown, as a string.

How can I find this, given the `errorObject` in the event handler?

```
window.onerror = function(errorMsg, url, lineNumber, colNumber, errorObject) {
    // ...
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsgtq1uc/)

`typeof` - just returns object. I could do `instanceof` and hardcode the list of error types from the MDN docs, but that doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the type of the error as a string with [`obj.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/name), giving you "TypeError" - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsgtq1uc/3/).